# login RESTFUL api which returns an id when login succeeds

Tags: java, android, api, authentication, restful-authentication

I have made a login api which will return an id when i pass username and password in android app.

```
public class LoginApiBody
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Say the link is http://abcd.org/efg/login.
Currently the link is showing:

```
{  
   "message": "The request is invalid.", 
   "messageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get(Int32)' in 'KnwPortal.Controllers.UsersAPIController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type,  a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter." 
}
```

I have to pass 'UserName' and 'Password' to the server with POST method.My question is in which format i should send/pass my username and password? whether in JSONObject or something else? how he can verify whether the passed UserName and Password is there on the server or not?
I have tried this, but no success

```
Ion.with(User_Activity.this)
        .load("http://abcd.org/efg/login")
        .setBodyParameter("UsserName",user)
        .setBodyParameter("Password",pass)
        .asString()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, Object result) {
                //on complete
            }
        });
```

or i am doing something wrong with my loginapi?

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to post data using ion. The official github documentation does not mention using "POST" in load. I was struck for days when  was using it for the first time

**Note: I found the following problem in the ION library code.Updating it will give you the results in form of String returned by your API.If your API is returning JSONObject try using `.asJSONObect()` instead of `.asString()`. you will also have to change the callback method apprpriately**

I would be happy to help if any error pops up

```
Ion.with(User_Activity.this)
            .load("POST","http://abcd.org/efg/login")
            .setBodyParameter("UsserName",user)
            .setBodyParameter("Password",pass)
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Object result) {
                    //on complete
                }
            });
```

You also need to give an Endpoint to your API, which i am not able to find in your question.

The ION library will do the work for encoding the data in url-encoded method. You dont need to add that. Its the server response method that must be set in ion. I have already told you how to do that. As i am not able to see the return data and endpoint of your api i wont be able to help you if there is any problem in API. Please add your API code as well if it does not work.

Comment: my API code is like this:   [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody]LoginApiBody login)
        {
            bool success = WebSecurity.Login(login.UserName, login.Password, false);
            if (success)
            {
                var UserID = GetUserID_By_UserName(login.UserName);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, UserID);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "0");
            }
        }

Comment: try adding "POST" like i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: if it works please mark it correct and upvote the answer